# Unable to get the api token field to fill in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to complete an api registration system using Laravel 5.8. At the minute every time I run a registration the api_token field remains null. I am pretty certain I have followed the instructions correctly but I am still running into the error.

This was the migration I created.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //

        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                        ->unique()
                        ->nullable()
                        ->default(null);
});

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and the following is the create method within the Registration Controller.

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);
    }
```

It is almost like the "api_token" field is being completely ignored during the process. All other fields are completed during the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first let me see: did you add **'api_token'** in the user **$fillable** array in your User model ?